# Inline select field elements needed always-Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile

I want the select field elements in a form designed for mobile using JQuery mobile. I am using a label followed by three select items. Now, I have two requirements:
1) The select field elements should always appear in a single line along with label.
2) On re-sizing the browser window, that is changing the width of the browser, the field elements should remain inline always.

I have used screen and device width attributes in CSS. I have also tried modifying the mobile UI CSS supplied by the JQuery. But it is not helping. Help. Its urgent :(

Link used:http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/selects/
Section: Horizontally grouped select inputs

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you've tried so we can help find the problem?

Comment: Please see the last two lines of my question. I have just added the code that I am using in the question (Link used, Section).

Comment: It's better to post your code.

Comment: I cant do that as it is confidential information of the company and the client; Eric, Omar. I have just used :Link used:http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/selects/
Section: Horizontally grouped select inputs. Now, I just want the select fields to be together always.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default css behaviour. Change the the control group div so that its always an inline block and change the field set so that no elements wrap.

```
div.ui-controlgroup-label{display:inline-block;} 
fieldset.ui-controlgroup-horizontal{white-space:nowrap;}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/vZcBM/ for example.

Alternatively you can set the fieldset's min-width.

```
fieldset.ui-controlgroup-horizontal{min-width: 400px;}
```

Comment: But the design is no longer responsive :( Could you please modify your code?

Comment: Responsive? You said you were looking for an inline block of elements. How do you want it to be responsive?

Comment: Inline (Point-1) as well as responsive(Point-2).

Comment: Sure, but what do you mean by responsive? A responsive element to me would be that it doesn't stay as an inline block when the screen is size is changed... i.e. the responsive nature of jquery mobile 1.3 http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/intro/rwd.php